# PL/SQL how to count an escape sequence as 1 character

Tags: regex, oracle, plsql, escaping

Sometimes my stored procedure will be called with a string of characters containing an embedded escape (ESC) sequence(s).  For example:  person types in `abc&def`, and the stored procedure will get the escaped equivalent: `abc&amp;def`.

The stored proc needs to

1. recognize that it received ESC sequence(s), and
2. must count each ESC sequence as 1 character during its length of string calculation.

So for the above string example, `abc&amp;def`, it would recognize this as having length 7 (representing the originally entered length of `abc&def`), so the characters `&amp;` would count as 1 character.

Is there a straight forward way to do this in PL/SQL? We're running 11g.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You just need to unescape the string. There's a trick to do that documented [here](http://www.pilcrow.nl/2011/04/unescape-html-entities-in-oracle):

```
SELECT DBMS_XMLGEN.CONVERT ('abc&amp;def',1)
      ,LENGTH(
         DBMS_XMLGEN.CONVERT ('abc&amp;def',1)
       )
FROM DUAL;

abc&def  7
```